# UEFI application for Creating ext2/3/4 Filesystem

Tags: linux, uefi, ext4

Almost all linux distro invoke an application during installation that formats storage drive into ext2/3/4 filesystem.
How is it done? Is it achieved by any UEFI application?

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , (in this case, I don't think so),  but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The creation of filesystems is unrelated to UEFI.

The Unix approach is to expose hardware resources as pseudo-files ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file)), so that the hardware can be accessed using standard file commands. In case of an HDD or SDD, the raw drive can be accessed via a device node such as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`. Depending on the hardware, you might also have a name such as `/dev/nvme0n1`. You can open these files and manipulate them as you would with other files (e.g. in C with `fopen`, `fread`, `fseek`, ...). The Linux kernel will map any write or read operations on these pseudo-files to the raw drive.

Usually you want to partition the drive before applying the filesystem (thought it would be possible to apply the filesystem directly to the full drive without any partitions). To create partitions, you would write a partition table (e.g. in GPT format) to the beginning of the drive. You can then create entries for your partitions in the partition table. After the partitions have been created, Linux should expose each partition as separate device nodes (e.g. `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2` or `/dev/nvme0n1p1`, `/dev/nvme0n1p2`). These files can again be opened and manipulated as with other files. The Linux kernel will again map write or read operations on these files to the raw drive, taking the offset of the partition into account.

To create a filesystem on a partition, you would then use a tool such as `mkfs.ext4` (part of [e2fsprogs](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/)). The `mkfs.ext4` will open the partition pseudo-file for the partition and write the filesystem data structure to this file. The Linux kernel will map the write operations onto the raw drive.

Let us consider the following example. We will create a new file and make the Linux kernel pretend that this file is a drive (using a loop device). We will then create a new partition table on this "drive" and then a filesystem on one of its partitions.

- Create a file of size 2G that will be used as our drive:

  ```
  # dd if=/dev/zero of=my_disk bs=1024 count=2000000
  2000000+0 records in
  2000000+0 records out
  2048000000 bytes (2,0 GB, 1,9 GiB) copied, 8,13332 s, 252 MB/s
  ```
- Create a loop device that lets us treat our file as a new drive:

  ```
  # losetup -f
  /dev/loop0
  # losetup -P /dev/loop0 my_disk
  ```
- Create a partition table on our disk:

  ```
  # fdisk /dev/loop0                                                   
  Command: g

  Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: 8155F57B-0E54-1146-9CC1-E5092C1F671C).

  Command: n
  Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
  First sector (2048-3999966, default 2048): 
  Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-3999966, default 3999966): 

  Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 1,9 GiB.

  Command: w
  ```

  You should now be able to see a new device node `/dev/loop0p1` for your newly created partition. If not try something like `partprobe` to notify the kernel of a change in the partition layout or remove the loop device with `losetup -d /dev/loop0` and open it again with the previous step.
- Create a filesystem on a partition of our drive:

  ```
  # mkfs.ext4 /dev/loop0p1 
  mke2fs 1.45.6 (20-Mar-2020)
  Discarding device blocks: done                            
  Creating filesystem with 499739 4k blocks and 125184 inodes
  Filesystem UUID: 09d1a2e7-4ef1-4a89-92ab-eae1a80d9534
  Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
       32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912

  Allocating group tables: done                            
  Writing inode tables: done                            
  Creating journal (8192 blocks): done
  Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
  ```

  You could also apply `strace` to observe the system calls used by `mkfs.ext4`. You chould be able to see `open` and `close` calls for `/dev/loop0p1` and also some `read` and `lseek`. You should not see any write operations. This is because `mkfs.ext4` seems to use `mmap` instead ([reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O)), where part of a file is mapped into memory, such that modifications to that memory will be written back to the file by the kernel (which is slightly faster than manually reading part of a file into a buffer, modifying the buffer and writing the buffer back to the file). But memory-mapping is not specific to files that are device nodes for partitions, you could also use `mmap` on a regular file.
- Mount the filesystem:

  ```
  # mount /dev/loop0p1 /mnt
  ```

  You could then for example create a file in `/mnt/`, unmount the filesystem and mount it again to verify that the file has been created on our new drive.

You can see that in the example the ext4 filesystem was created by accessing the device node for the partition of our drive. During the installation of a typical Linux distribution, the filesystem will be created in the same way, except with device nodes of a partition on a real drive, instead of the loop device used in our example.

References:

- Arch Linux Installation Guide: [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Format_the_partitions)
- Gentoo Installation Handbook: [link](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Creating_file_systems)

Comment: Your first sentence `The creation of filesystems is unrelated to UEFI.` is rubbish. For your information, as far back as the early 2000s, (U)EFI utilities have been available to partition, format and check supported (U)EFI filesystems.  Intel even released a package - efidiskutils - in 2000 specifically for that purpose.

Comment: @fpmurphy Sure, there are EFI programs for all kinds of tasks. There is probably an EFI program for running a TCP server. But I would consider TCP to be unrelated to EFI, in the sense that understanding TCP does not require me to know anything about EFI, it existed long before EFI and a book or lecture about TCP would likely not have any mention of EFI. I think filesystems are similar to that. Understanding filesystems and **how** a typical Linux distribution sets up a filesystem does not require any knowledge of EFI. Let me know if you think there is a more fitting word than "unrelated".